# Are aluminum anti-seize and silver anti-seize different?

Tags: maintenance

I asked someone to pick up some silver anti-seize (which I'd seen recommended) and they came back with aluminum anti-seize.  Is there a difference?

I could imagine that, when used between aluminum and steel, you wouldn't want aluminum in the anti-seize.

Comment: What I have is Permatex Aluminum Anti-Sieze Lubricant #80071.

Comment: Personally I'd use it with confidence!

Comment: For bicycle purposes, I don’t think the difference will be significant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anti-seize compound exists to prevent galling, which according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galling) is a problem with metal parts in sliding contact, particularly parts under high pressure with stationary or slow-speed contact.  Some metals, such as aluminum and stainless steel, are more prone to galling than other materials, like hardened steel.

Loctite make a brand of anti-seize compound, Loctite 37565, that is marketed as "Silver Anti-Seize", that they say is "fortified with graphite and metallic flake"; they don't say anything about the product actually containing silver, so I think "silver" is a marketing term.  The metallic flake in it might well be aluminum (copper also seems to be popular).  I couldn't tell you whether aluminum or "silver" anti-seize is better, but I do know from personal experience that if you're using stainless steel fasteners, any kind of anti-seize compound is much better than none.

Answer (score 0):

Anti-seize definitely helps. Not sure which one is better Silver or Aluminum because I haven't tried both. I use aluminum one and I am happy with it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you want to include a link to your own site, your profile is the place to do that. Links in answers should be relevant to that answer; otherwise, it starts to look like you're just trying to drive traffic away from us and towards you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the description for the Permatex 'silver grade' anti-seize, the description says "A highly refined blend of aluminum, copper and graphite" - so I think 'silver' and the same as what other brands call 'alu' anti-seize.